# How can I preserve / maintain consecutive newlines in Ruby here-document?

Tags: ruby, newline, heredoc

I wonder how can I preserve consecutive newline characters with Ruby here-document? In my program all of them are collapsed to one newline. For example:

```
s=<<END
1
2

3


4



END
```

evaluates to:

```
s="1\n2\n3\n4\n"
```

However I would like to preserve the consecutive newlines when for example formatting a BBcode document a letter or something similar.

Comment: I don't see this behavior in irb for Ruby 1.9.3p392.  How are you running this code, and in what version of Ruby?

Comment: Ruby 2.0, and the Pry interpreter instead of IRB.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug to me.  Have you tried a multiline `%q`?

```
s=%q(1
2

3


4



)
```